# When does Inspector in unity assign variable?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Say i have a public list of integers then of course I will see the list in unity inspector and i can assign multiple values inside it. My question is when the list will actually assign the values to the variables in the game?? Does it assign values in "OnEnable()", "OnAwake()", "OnStart()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## During deserialization

Which occurs *before* any method of that script's code is called.

If you want to run code at that point in time, you need an [ISerializationCallbackReceiver](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html). Note that the intended use of this interface is to serialize/deserialize certain complex Types (such as dictionaries) for use in the Inspector; I have not attempted to use this in a runtime capacity even though the interface does appear to be in `UnityEngine` not `UnityEditor`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I just have one for small question. should i use inspector to assign simple variables (eg. like stamina or health of my character ) in game ??

Comment: Absolutely.  That functionality is used everywhere in Unity.